# Hibernate newbie help in netbeans

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, annotations

I study hibernate, AFAIK you can use xml or annotation, I like annotation more so trying this method.

1. Automatically created hibernate.cfg.xml (Netbeans wizard)
2. Automatically created reverse engineering xml
3. Automatically created HibernateUtil.java
4. Automatically created POJO class with annotations

[image]

then code:

```
    SessionFactory session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    CallInfo ci = new CallInfo(1234567); //POJO class
    session.getCurrentSession().save(ci);
```

and hibernate still wants the xml, why?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at ru.asteros.sochi.feedback.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:28)
at ru.asteros.sochi.feedback.SochiFeedback.main(SochiFeedback.java:52)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: ru/asteros/sochi/feedback/CallInfo.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:563)
```

Comment: Check your generated `HibernateUtil` and make sure it is using `AnnotationConfiguration` and not `Configuration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably `CallInfo.hbm.xml` is referenced in `hibernate.cfg.hbm` and its not in valid class path

Comment: you're right, it was there.. So I've removed that line in XML and now Java says: 

`Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:542)
 at ru.asteros.sochi.feedback.SochiFeedback.main(SochiFeedback.java:54)`

Comment: see, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281045/why-do-i-get-org-hibernate-hibernateexception-no-currentsessioncontext-configur