# Getting org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created a maven project with hibernate 5.4 and successfully created DAOs now when I try to get Hibernate Session via `getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()` I get Exception **org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!** although I have already added
`<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>` in **hibernate.cfg.xml** file. Already checked several forums including this question [org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159966/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-no-currentsessioncontext-configured) but unable to solve it,

**Here is the hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">onetozero</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.112:3306/ecdis</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="Domain.Route"/>
        <mapping class="Domain.RoutePoint"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**HibernateSession Class**

```
public class HibernateSession {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

and this is how I am using getting the List via DAO

```
public List<T> list() {
        Session session = HibernateSession.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        CriteriaQuery<T> query = session.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(entityClass);
        query.select(query.from(entityClass));
        return session.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
```

I am new new to Java and Hibernate, also not using any framework atm so a little detail can also go along the way. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HibernateSession.getSessionFactory().openSession() rather than getCurrentSession() to get session, then session factory will bind session to current context as you are using current session context class thread not JTA.[Details here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2384979&sid=8367751b54bf160003b867f858393398)